# How to Run cmd command in new powershell instance as administrator

Tags: powershell, cmd, runas

I am trying to run 2 cmd command in PowerShell but an error displayed.

**CMD**

```
cd C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin
.\jmeter -n -t C:\User-search.jmx -l C:\Result.jtl
```

**Error**

```
PS C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin> .\jmeter -n -t C:\User-search.jmx -l C:\Result.jtl
.\jmeter : 'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
At line:1 char:1
+ .\jmeter -n -t C:\User-search.jmx -l C:\Result.jtl
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('findstr' is no...ternal command,:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

operable program or batch file.
Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
errorlevel=2
```

When I open new PowerShell instance with runas administrator then the command runs successfully.

I tried the below command and it opens the new PowerShell window as administrator but error is same

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs ".\jmeter -n -t C:\User-search.jmx -l C:\Result.jtl"
```

**Error**

```
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
errorlevel=2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I am able to run it...

Actually, before running Jmeter I added below 3 paths to the Path environment variable.

```
C:\Windows\System32
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin
C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin
```

Now I removed the 3rd path i.e 'C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin' and run the command inside ScriptBlock

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
cd C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin
.\jmeter -n -t C:\User-search.jmx -l C:\Result.jtl
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run only without removing the third step '`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
.\jmeter -n -t C:\User-search.jmx -l C:\Result.jtl
}`

Comment: Not able to find the java executable or version error displayed. I think we already change directory using powershell so it does not required in the path variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cmdlet `Invoke-Command` to execute a command with a specific credential:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
      Set-Location C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin
      & C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\jmeter -n -t C:\User-search.jmx -l C:\Result.jtl
} -Credential Administrator
```

Please test it and let me know!

Comment: Same error. Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.

Comment: What file extension does the file C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\jmeter have?

Comment: No extension. Its a file type.

Comment: Make sure you have set the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable, so the computer knows, where java is located:
https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/

Comment: Yes, it is already set. It is working fine with new powershell instance.

Comment: Please try out the updated answer with the "Set-Location" in it

Comment: I am sorry then I am probably not able to help you

Comment: No Problem. Thanks for trying. It is tricky or maybe I am doing some mistake. Will update here if I got the answer.